# tengo un problema: no migra mis datos de mi tabla

Tags: php, laravel

Esta es la de la tabla `tipoAutos`:

```
Schema::create('tipoAutos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('tipoAuto');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Y esta la de la tabla `automoviles`:

```
Schema::create('automoviles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('patente',6)->unique();
    $table->string('marca');
    $table->string('modelo');
    $table->string('color');
    $table->string('VIN',17)->unique();
    $table->integer('ano');
    $table->integer('automovil_id')->unsigned(); 
    $table->integer('kilometros');
    $table->integer('precio');
    $table->double('cc_Motor');
    $table->enum('transmision', ['Mecánico', 'Automático', 'Semi-Automático']);
    $table->enum('tipo_combustible', ['Bencina', 'Petroleo', 'Eléctrico']);
    $table->enum('traccion', ['Delantera', 'Trasera', 'Integral/4X4']);

    //campo auxilliares de Laravel
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes(); //Nueva línea, para el borrado lógico

    $table->foreign('automovil_id')->references('id')->on('tipoAutos');
});
```

En consola me sale este error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `concesionaria`.`automoviles` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `automoviles` add constraint `automoviles_automovil_id_foreign` foreign key (`automovil_id`) references `tipoAutos` (`id`))

Comment: la 5.7 esa es la que uso, php artisan
Laravel Framework 5.7.29

Comment: El código se ve bien. ¿Estás seguro de que la migracioń de `tipoAutos` corre primero y la de `automoviles` después? El orden de ejecución se lo dá el timestamp que tiene el nombre de cada archivo de migraciones.

Comment: antes los tenia desordenado, ahora les cambie el orden en el seeder, pero esta todo igual

Comment: no mi error, pensaba que eran los seeder que te referias, pero a que te refieres con eso del orden de timestamp?

Comment: A los nombres de los archivos de las migraciones

Comment: **YA LO SOLUCIONE:** TENIA UN ERROR CON LA MIGRACIÓN, MIGRABA ANTES AUTOMÓVILES QUE TIPO DE AUTOS, ESE ERA MI ERROR, BORRE AUTOMÓVILES, INSERTE LOS DATOS Y FUNCIONÓ

Comment: Esa explicación de cómo lo solucionaste no sirve para el sitio. O escribes una respuesta detallada que sirva a otros programadores que tengan el mismo problema, o elimina la pregunta para que no genere ruido.

Answer (score 1):

creo que pueden haber 2 alternativas a tu problema, el primero es intentar cambiando el tipo de dato, que en ocaciones ocasiona conflictos el tipo de dato `integer()->unsigned()` cuando existe un incremental(id) de esta forma:

```
$table->integer('automovil_id')->unsigned();
```

Por esta:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('automovil_id');
```

La segunda alternativa intentar reconstruir tu base de datos con
`php artisan migrate:refresh` el cual toma todas tus migraciones les hace un rollback y las reconstruye, con esto puedes ver si el problema es tuyo o de laravel, si tienes sedeers añades el `--seed` al final del comando,

Además puede que tengas creado el migrate de la tabla automóviles antes que la de tipo de vehículos, revisa el nombre del archivo, estas se ordenan por fecha de creación, ya que al correr el migrate las corre en ese orden especifico.

Comment: intente tus métodos, me sigue saliendo exactamente los mismo (el mismo error en consola)

Comment: ya lo resolvi, era que automoviles lo cree antes que tipoAutos

Comment: Eso te lo comente como la ultima alternativa, el migrate siempre se corre en orden de la fecha de creación, genial que pudieras resolverlo.